# Errors logging into Android application

Tags: java, android, sql

I have build a simple Android application using eclipse to connect the login and register data entry with the local  server (I have user both `xampp` and `wamp`) through `JSON web service`, the application at the beginning worked fine but the it has stopped working.

Log cat follows:

```
01-28 16:59:57.399: W/KeyCharacterMap(329): No keyboard for id 0
01-28 16:59:57.399: W/KeyCharacterMap(329): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
01-28 16:59:59.859: D/request!(329): starting
01-28 17:00:01.640: D/dalvikvm(329): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 7273 objects / 291632 bytes in 264ms
01-28 17:00:06.109: E/JSON Parser(329): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <HTML><TITLE>404 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
01-28 17:00:06.121: W/dalvikvm(329): threadid=7: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
01-28 17:00:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(329): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
01-28 17:00:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(329): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
01-28 17:00:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
01-28 17:00:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
01-28 17:00:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
01-28 17:00:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
01-28 17:00:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
01-28 17:00:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
01-28 17:00:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
01-28 17:00:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
01-28 17:00:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(329): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-28 17:00:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at com.example.mysqltest.Login$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(Login.java:125)
01-28 17:00:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at com.example.mysqltest.Login$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(Login.java:1)
01-28 17:00:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
01-28 17:00:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
01-28 17:00:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  ... 4 more
01-28 17:00:09.540: E/WindowManager(329): Activity com.example.mysqltest.Login has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4a6e0df0 that was originally added here
01-28 17:00:09.540: E/WindowManager(329): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.mysqltest.Login has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4a6e0df0 that was originally added here
01-28 17:00:09.540: E/WindowManager(329):   at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:247)
01-28 17:00:09.540: E/WindowManager(329):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
01-28 17:00:09.540: E/WindowManager(329):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
01-28 17:00:09.540: E/WindowManager(329):   at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
01-28 17:00:09.540: E/WindowManager(329):   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
01-28 17:00:09.540: E/WindowManager(329):   at com.example.mysqltest.Login$AttemptLogin.onPreExecute(Login.java:103)
01-28 17:00:09.540: E/WindowManager(329):   at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
01-28 17:00:09.540: E/WindowManager(329):   at com.example.mysqltest.Login.onClick(Login.java:77)
01-28 17:00:09.540: E/WindowManager(329):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
01-28 17:00:09.540: E/WindowManager(329):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
01-28 17:00:09.540: E/WindowManager(329):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-28 17:00:09.540: E/WindowManager(329):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-28 17:00:09.540: E/WindowManager(329):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-28 17:00:09.540: E/WindowManager(329):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-28 17:00:09.540: E/WindowManager(329):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-28 17:00:09.540: E/WindowManager(329):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-28 17:00:09.540: E/WindowManager(329):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-28 17:00:09.540: E/WindowManager(329):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-28 17:00:09.540: E/WindowManager(329):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-28 17:00:14.370: I/Process(329): Sending signal. PID: 329 SIG: 9
01-28 17:01:01.940: D/request!(359): starting
01-28 17:01:07.964: E/JSON Parser(359): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <HTML><TITLE>404 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
01-28 17:01:07.964: W/dalvikvm(359): threadid=7: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
01-28 17:01:07.979: E/AndroidRuntime(359): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
01-28 17:01:07.979: E/AndroidRuntime(359): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
01-28 17:01:07.979: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
01-28 17:01:07.979: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
01-28 17:01:07.979: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
01-28 17:01:07.979: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
01-28 17:01:07.979: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
01-28 17:01:07.979: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
01-28 17:01:07.979: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
01-28 17:01:07.979: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
01-28 17:01:07.979: E/AndroidRuntime(359): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-28 17:01:07.979: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at com.example.mysqltest.Login$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(Login.java:125)
01-28 17:01:07.979: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at com.example.mysqltest.Login$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(Login.java:1)
01-28 17:01:07.979: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
01-28 17:01:07.979: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
01-28 17:01:07.979: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  ... 4 more
01-28 17:01:08.119: D/dalvikvm(359): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 3000 objects / 191520 bytes in 137ms
01-28 17:01:08.219: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(359): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
01-28 17:01:10.639: E/WindowManager(359): Activity com.example.mysqltest.Login has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4a6b5db0 that was originally added here
01-28 17:01:10.639: E/WindowManager(359): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.mysqltest.Login has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4a6b5db0 that was originally added here
01-28 17:01:10.639: E/WindowManager(359):   at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:247)
01-28 17:01:10.639: E/WindowManager(359):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
01-28 17:01:10.639: E/WindowManager(359):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
01-28 17:01:10.639: E/WindowManager(359):   at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
01-28 17:01:10.639: E/WindowManager(359):   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
01-28 17:01:10.639: E/WindowManager(359):   at com.example.mysqltest.Login$AttemptLogin.onPreExecute(Login.java:103)
01-28 17:01:10.639: E/WindowManager(359):   at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
01-28 17:01:10.639: E/WindowManager(359):   at com.example.mysqltest.Login.onClick(Login.java:77)
01-28 17:01:10.639: E/WindowManager(359):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
01-28 17:01:10.639: E/WindowManager(359):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
01-28 17:01:10.639: E/WindowManager(359):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-28 17:01:10.639: E/WindowManager(359):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-28 17:01:10.639: E/WindowManager(359):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-28 17:01:10.639: E/WindowManager(359):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-28 17:01:10.639: E/WindowManager(359):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-28 17:01:10.639: E/WindowManager(359):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-28 17:01:10.639: E/WindowManager(359):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-28 17:01:10.639: E/WindowManager(359):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-28 17:01:10.639: E/WindowManager(359):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-28 17:01:11.429: I/Process(359): Sending signal. PID: 359 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Eclipse is just the IDE, Java is your language, so more significant in this case.

Comment: There is a NPE in your logs. Post the code

Answer (score 0):

It's looking like a null pointer exception at line 125 of Login.java:

```
01-28 17:01:07.979: E/AndroidRuntime(359): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-28 17:01:07.979: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at com.example.mysqltest.Login$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(Login.java:125)
```

Without seeing your code it's hard to help further, but check for the use of uninitialized views/variables.

Comment: thank you so much for your help but I'm not sure what do you mean by uninitialized views/variables?? Further more I will try to upload the codes

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this site..an any body tell me how to upload my eclipse code here?? thanks